# Different environment support for java gradle project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, build.gradle, maven-cargo

My java project is using Gradle for build and deployment. Currently we have three environment,
dev, test and prod. Each env is hosted on different box. To deploy my project to these box, all I do is changing Host in build.gradle, hibernate.properties and mongo.properties.
my build.gradle has below section, which handles hostname for deployment,

```
cargo {
    containerId = 'tomcat7x'
    port = 8080
    context = 'projectContext'
    remote {
        hostname = '<hostName>'
        username = '<username>'
        password = '<password>'
    }
```

Problem is everytime I do some change, I have to manually change this  and run,
'gradle :cargoRedeployRemote' to deploy my project. I need a more handy way to handle these env for CI/CD integration. 
Please leave your thoughts.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Do you want to deploy these changes to all env in some kind of loop?

Comment: Requirement is that whenever some new code is checked in, new build should automatically be deployed to all these environment. It can be some invoking 'gradle cargoRedeployRemote' command multiple times.